# how to get ajax page content using php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I would like to read odds from the following site:
http://uk.wettportal.com/Soccer/England/Premier_League/Arsenal_FC_-_Everton_FC_963003.html

The odds are loaded dynamically using ajax. The source page does not contain the odds. Is there any technique to get content of such page using php?

Comment: Ajax is just a codeword for "Making HTTP Requests". PHP can make HTTP requests. The [terms of use for that site](http://uk.wettportal.com/terms/) forbid quite a lot of the things you might plan to do with that data.

Comment: So it is fine to use, but only for personal use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data-url is fixed you could use it right away with a simple php one-liner:
`$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://domain.com/data.json'));`

If the 'ajax' data url is not fixed, you first need to get the hostpage (above line minus the json_decode) and get the actual data-link from it.

*Note:* if the author of the website did his job correctly there might be measures in place against this, like: checking referrer, browser's http headers, session-cookie, etc.
That would make it more difficult (never impossible) to get the data.

In such cases you would use CURL or php's [fsockopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) (doc here) and *emulate* a browser.
Don't forget cookie-handling (since that site uses that!!! I sniffed the traffic) and probably the referrer (the url of the hostpage).  Also don't forget the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header.

---

Example (for your case):

From the function `refresh_odds` one can see how those data-url's are built (I cleaned up formatting so it's nice 'n easy to read):

```
var url = "/lib/ajax/getEventResult.php";
var data = "event_id=" + $("#event_id").val() 
         + "&partner=" + $("#partner").val() 
         + "&lang=" + $("#language").val();

var url = "/lib/ajax/getOddsTable.php";
var data = "partner=" + $("#partner").val() 
         + "&lang=" + $("#language").val() 
         + "&period=" + $("#period").val() 
         + "&betgame=" + $("#betgame").val() 
         + "&eventmode=" + $("#eventmode").val() 
         + "&event_id=" + $("#event_id").val() 
         + "&bettype=" + $("#bettype").val();
```

Now you know what the hidden input field-id's are that your php-script has to search for in the host-page in order to construct a live data-url.

---

**Update** (as per your comment)

The odd's tab does:

```
$("#period").val("fulltime");
refresh_odds();
```

the period tab does:

```
$("#period").val(period);
refresh_odds();
```

See how it goes back to `refresh_odds()` ... ?

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for answer! using file_get_contents I'll get only the content of the tab that is loaded by default (1X2). My question is how to get odds from other tabs (Over/Under, Handicap, etc.).

Comment: So to get odds from 1x2 tab I need the following data-url: http://uk.wettportal.com/lib/ajax/getOddsTable.php?partner=wettportal&lang=en&period=fulltime&betgame=&eventmode=upcoming&event_id=963003&bettype=3way. Am I right? To get odds from other tabs I need to modify <bettype> parameter.

Comment: Updated my answer. Note that it still boils down to my original answer where the data-url is built.

Comment: When I use the mentioned data-url as argument of file_get_contents I get the following message  "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!".

Comment: Then you need php's `fsockopen` ([doc here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)) and emulate a browser. Don't forget cookie-handling (since that site uses that!!! I sniffed the traffic) and probably a referrer. Also don't forget the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header.

Comment: Provided answer is correct. I mange to get odds from all tabs using CURL and tips provided by GitaarLAB (session cookie obtained from the host page, host page url used as referrer, X-Requested-With header to simulate ajax query). Thank you!